# How do I have a date variable recalculate or update itself when it's called?

Tags: swift

In the app, when a user taps a job as complete, I collect a timestamp for later use.[image: before] [image: after]
That way I can show when the job was completed in another view.

The problem I have is that the variable doesn't change when a user taps a job done.

Here is what the data struct looks like when I print it out:

```
Moneypants.Points(user: "Father", itemName: "enter your top priority habit here", itemCategory: "daily habits", code: "C", valuePerTap: 24, itemDate: 1511579837.027503), 
Moneypants.Points(user: "Father", itemName: "pray & scripture study", itemCategory: "daily habits", code: "C", valuePerTap: 6, itemDate: 1511579837.027503), 
Moneypants.Points(user: "Father", itemName: "exercise (20 min)", itemCategory: "daily habits", code: "C", valuePerTap: 6, itemDate: 1511579837.027503), 
Moneypants.Points(user: "Father", itemName: "journal", itemCategory: "daily habits", code: "C", valuePerTap: 6, itemDate: 1511579837.027503), 
Moneypants.Points(user: "Father", itemName: "1-on-1 time with kid", itemCategory: "daily habits", code: "C", valuePerTap: 6, itemDate: 1511579837.027503)
```

As you can see, the timestamp for each item is identical (they each show the timestamp of "1511579837.027503"), despite the fact that I tapped each item separately a few seconds apart.

**CODE**

```
class UserVC: UIViewController {   
    var selectedDate: Date!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    selectedDate = Date()
```

When user taps the cell to mark the job complete, this is the code that runs:

```
let pointsArrayItem = Points(user: currentUserName,
                             itemName: (usersDailyJobs?[indexPath.row].name)!,
                             itemCategory: "daily jobs",
                             code: "C",
                             valuePerTap: dailyJobsPointValue,
                             itemDate: (selectedDate?.timeIntervalSince1970)!)

Points.pointsArray.append(pointsArrayItem)
```

I think it's pretty simple, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You are setting the value of `selectedDate` only once, when the view loads. You probably want to set it on tap. Like: `... itemDate: Date().timeIntervalSince1970)`

Comment: Not related to your question but you should get rid of `"my "` from your tab items title.

Comment: Yes, but that won't work if user changes the date to anything other than today. If you look at the page, you'll see that the user can choose which day to mark their jobs.

Comment: How do I set the value outside the 'ViewDidLoad'?

Comment: Thanks for the thought, @LeoDabus. That "my" is the clients request. Is there a reason I should get rid of it? Will Apple reject it if I don't?

Comment: You should convince them that it is not needed. It is redundant.

Comment: And capitalize your titles

Comment: @LeoDabus I'll let them know. Thanks for the suggestion! As for my initial question, any insight?

Comment: I think you can name it whatever you want. Try checking the guidelines https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new variable for the date so that I could "refresh" the `selectedDate` variable. Now my class has a variable `var selectedDateNumber` which is then set in the `ViewDidLoad` method with a default value.

```
class UserVC: UIViewController {
    ...
    var selectedDateNumber: Int!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    selectedDateNumber = 0
}
```

Then when I need to "refresh" it with the current date / timestamp, I use this code inside my various functions:

```
selectedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: selectedDateNumber, to: Date())
```

By refreshing the data this way, I can get a current timestamp for my project, including timestamps for previous days.